# Postfix header_checks are ignored

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, dovecot, smtp-headers

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I installed Postfix (v3.4.13) with Dovecot (v2.3.7.2) a long time ago. Now, I want to overwrite the Message-Id header using header_checks. It's the first time I'm trying to use this feature, so it hasn't been tested before. The problem is that Postfix seems to be ignoring these rules.

In `/etc/postfix/header_checks` there is only one line: `/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@default.tld>/ REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@newhost.tld>`

At first, I thought that I might have misspelled something, but the command `postmap -q "Message-Id: <20230715114559.D6E1B44C11@default.tld>" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` returns the correct response. After that, I checked the configuration files. `main.cf` contains the setting `header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks`, so it seems fine. The mail logs also don't contain any information about this issue.

While searching online (including this forum and the Postfix documentation), I came across some information about the `receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks` rule that could potentially block the `header_checks`, but it seems that `receive_override_options` is not even set.

Here is the output of postconf -n (some private values are overwritten with `(Hidden)`):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = (Hidden)
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/(Hidden)/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/(Hidden)/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtputf8_enable = no
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this for outbound or inbound mail? If outbound, why are you trying to do it with header checks instead of configuring the hostname of your server? If inbound, that would probably just break ordering messages as threads in MUAs.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Basically, it is intended for outbound emails. The hostname is also used for other services and, unfortunately, I can't change it now. The main point is that header_checks also don't work with other rules. I am unable to add new headers, remove them, or manipulate them in other ways, if it becomes necessary in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `postmap` with lookup type `regexp` but your config has lookup type `pcre`. These are different dictionary types. Check if you have `pcre` enabled with `postconf -m`.

Comment: I have already tried different types, such as `regexp` and `pcre` in `main.cf`. `postconf -m` returns the following enabled configurations: `btree, cidr, environ, fail, hash, inline, internal, memcache, mysql, nis, pcre, pipemap, proxy, randmap, regexp, socketmap, static, tcp, texthash, unionmap, unix`.